# Use JavaScript to intercept data received in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a webpage that will receive data in JSON format for every x minutes. I want to get its URL and content.

Manually I can do by using Network tab in Chrome DevTools to view it and copy its respond.

[image]

But my question is how do I make it intercept the file automatically. May someone guides me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monkey patch?

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (function(fopen){
    return function(){
        //do something, intercept here
        return fopen.apply(this,arguments); 
    }
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open)
```

Comment: Thanks, the code does execute when new data received. But how do I get its data(respond)?

Comment: this.responseText OR this.response based on what the responseType was. I advise you thoroughly look at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: you check the response within the onload handler.

Comment: Can `XMLHttpRequest.response` be used?

Comment: not like that, that property is not directly on the constructor, its on the instance => `var x = new XMLHttpRequest; x.onload = function(){....this.response...}`